# How to make Firebase user in flutter outside the google sign in function?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I made an app in which you can sign in with a Google account, and I want to have a variable to store whether the user is logged in or not and upload it to Firestore. But to use the update data function, I need to pass in a user object, which is only available in the google sign in function. So how can I make a user outside google sign in?

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class AuthService {
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;

  bool loggedIn = false;

  Observable<FirebaseUser> user; //firebase user
  Observable<Map<String, dynamic>> profile; //custom user data in Firestore
  PublishSubject loading = PublishSubject();

  //constructor
  AuthService() {
    user = Observable(_auth.onAuthStateChanged);
    profile = user.switchMap((FirebaseUser u) {
      if (u != null) {
        return _db.collection('users').document(u.uid).snapshots().map((
            snap) => snap.data);
      } else {
        return Observable.just({});
      }
    });
  }


  Future<String> testSignInWithGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
    await googleUser.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential))
        .user;
    assert(user.email != null);
    assert(user.displayName != null);
    assert(!user.isAnonymous);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);


    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

    loggedIn = true;

    updateUserData(user);

    return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
  }

  void updateUserData(FirebaseUser user) async {
    DocumentReference ref = _db.collection('users').document(user.uid);

    //loggedIn = true;

    return ref.setData({
      'uid': user.uid,
      'email': user.email,
      'photoURL': user.photoUrl,
      'displayName': user.displayName,
      'lastSeen': DateTime.now(),
      'loggedIn': loggedIn,
    }, merge: true);
  }

  void signOut() {
    _auth.signOut();
    loggedIn = false;
  }
}

final AuthService authService = AuthService();
```

Comment: Did my answer help your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question, you want to manipulate the Firebase user. You can create Firebase users with multiple methods, not just the GoogleSignIn one. After that you can update the user with a series of [methods from the `firebase_auth` package](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/lib/src/firebase_user.dart).

Here are a couple of simple examples:

```
FirebaseUser _firebaseUser;
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
```

---

```
void registerFirebaseUser(String email, String password){
  _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email,
    password: password
  ).then((AuthResult authResult) {
    _firebaseUser = authResult.user;
  });
}

void updateFirebaseUsername(String username) {
  UserUpdateInfo userUpdateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
  userUpdateInfo.displayName = username;

  _firebaseUser.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo);
}
```

Comment: And how can I send the value of the loggedIn bool to the server?

Comment: Why would you need to send that value to the server? The server knows you are authenticated and can make requests. You don't need to manage that.

Comment: Oh, you are right! I didn't thought of that, I need loggedIn, to show whether logging in was succesful or not, do I need to display a loading screen or not, but I don't need to send it to the server for that. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with your app!